# Get only 3 records using with from many to many relationship Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, many-to-many, relationship

> I'm using laravel 7 and
> I have 3 tables shown below. I want first three students data instead of all student. tables have many to many relationship.

1. groups

- id
- name

2. students

- id
- name

3. group_student_pivot

- group_id
- student_id
- created_at

I have below relationship in models

```
Groups model
public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class,'group_student_pivot')->withPivot(['status'])->withTimestamps();
    }


Student model
public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class,'group_student_pivot')->withPivot(['status'])->withTimestamps();
    }
```

```
$groups = Group::whereIn('id',$groupIds)->with('students')->get();
```

In above query I want first 3 students data instead of all students.

Comment: And what did you try so far to filter them out? You are just showing the basic relationship setup.

Comment: @Aless55 I tried below code but it's not working.

```public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class,'group_student_pivot')->withPivot(['status'])->withTimestamps()->take(3);
    }```

Comment: @Aless55 I also tried Attribute on group model  and it works but it fires many queries so I don't want to slow down performance  of the API.
```public function getFirstThreeStudentsAttribute()
    {
        return $this->students()->with(['user','user.image'])->latest()->limit(3)->get();
    }```

Answer (score 0):

You can get 3 records like this:

```
$groups = Group::whereIn('id',$groupIds)->with('students', function($q){
                $q->take(3);
            })->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but this isn't working. It only provide  3 student instead of 3 students for each groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can use with and whereHas method

```
$groups = Group::with('students')->whereHas('students', function($q){
            $q->take(3);
        })->whereIn('id',$groupIds)->get();
```

Comment: Then it'll only return groups which has students or return empty response.
Not working for me.